# Add active class to parent nav when on child pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to highlight the parent nav item when a user is within a child page based on the URL.

User is currently on the page **foo1-child** and the parent is **foo1** so I need to add the active class to **Foo 1**: `http://foo.com/foo1/foo1-child.html`

#### NAV:

```
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li><a href="/foo.com/foo1.html">Foo 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/foo.com/foo5.html">Foo 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have no issue adding an active class to links within the nav as I just compare every the href in the `.nav li a` vs the URL but how can I check the URL for a matching anchor link name in the URL or something similar?

#### Current JS

```
  $('.main-nav li > a').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(location.pathname) !== -1) {
      $this.addClass('active');
    }
  });
```

Comment: what your doing seems to be right. what problem are you facing with your script ?

Comment: Can you give some more info about your app. Do you have a back end or is it entirely a front end app? Either way, I imagine a router may help you, or some conditional statements on the links to add classes. But need more info please.

Comment: I have no access to the back end code, and the app isnt using any javascript mvc framework, it just has jQuery.

Comment: @DanMitchell - your JS worked for me! I've been looking all over for one that would handle my child pages. Not sure why it's not working for you, but I thought I'd let you know that it at least worked for me (on a custom WordPress site). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cut off the ".html" from the end of both of them and you search for the a's href (which should be shorter) in the location, it should work.

```
  $('.main-nav li > a').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var loc = location.
    if (location.pathname.replace(/\/[^\/]*\.html$/, '').startsWith($this.attr('href').replace(/\.html$/, ''))) {
      $this.parent().addClass('active');
    }
  });
```

You can see it in "action" here: https://jsfiddle.net/c8u2f91v/ Note it uses a fake location_pathname instead of location.pathname, because jsfiddle doesn't have the necessary prefixes in the path, but it shows that it should work.

Comment: Changed. If this is still not ok, then please also add to the question more examples of possible pages, possible breadcrumb links.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added pathname

Comment: It looks like the problem is in codepen. The url is like: /boomerang/d64e88d0d8c483755855f22336dcd9f71454177965519, so the comparsion doesn't work.